# Angular Js Expression not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new AngularJS. It's really fun, but I am facing some problem with this expression. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <style>
          p{
              height: 600px;
              width: 600px;
              font-size:17px;  
          }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
           <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="editor">
            <label for="kys_font_size"> font size:</label>
            <select ng-model="kys_selected_font" id="fontsize" name="kys_font_size" ng-options="page for page in FontSize(1, 150)" ng-change="changeFont()">
               </select>   
                <p contenteditable="true"  id="content"  ng-change="print()" >
                </p>
               <input type="text"  ng-model="name1">
                 <p >{{name1}}</p>
          </div>
         <p></p>
         <script>
           var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
             app.controller('editor',function($scope){
               $scope.name1="jpos"
                $scope.kys_selected_font = "hi there";
                 $scope.fonttext="hello";
                 $scope.FontSize = function(start, end) {
                                      var size = [];
                                       for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                                       size.push(i);
                                       }
                            return size;
                      };
                 $scope.print= function(){
                 };

                           $scope.changeFont = function(){
                               $("#content").append("<b size='3'  '> This is some text </b>");

                              $("#one").focus();
                           };
             });
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This gives me an {{Name1}} as output. Can someone please tell me where I have gone wrong with this code?

Comment: you should define app and controller .

Comment: I have did tha in div tag

Comment: I believe they mean your JS

Comment: you still need to write javascript, not only html.

Comment: @Jois Having just `ng-app="myApp"` and `ng-controller="sumit"` in your markup doesn't mean anything if you haven't already registered said controllers and modules against angular. `angular.module('test', [])` etc. I'm surprised angular hasn't thrown an exception in your console over it.

Comment: You've included a controller and called 'testing'. This needs to be added in a js file. Read the documentation here will help understand what they mean https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: @Jois Just put your editted code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjstf0Lf/) You using `ngChange` without `ngModel`. If you press `F12` and look in devtools the exception will tell you.

Comment: @ste2425 i know that! but whats wrong with ng-model="name1" ?? it's noy working

Comment: @Jois You are mistaken. It has nothing to do with the `ng-model="name1"` but the lack of `ngModel` on the element with the `ngChange` directive. It says in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) that `ngChange` also needs `ngModel` present on the same element. So in this case i believe that is a `p` element.

Comment: @ste2425 can u please help me out with this?? can i contact you by any chance?

Comment: @ste2425 finally it's clear . ThankYou . hey i just started a repo on github do you mind joining me? https://github.com/Sumanthjois/Curve

Comment: I have created a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108417/angular-js-expression-not-working) on Stack Overflow so we can talk about this more if you like without clogging up the comments.

Answer (score 3):

you should define app and controller .

**Update answer:**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
 app.controller('editor',function($scope){
 $scope.name1="jpos"
  $scope.kys_selected_font = "hi there";
  $scope.fonttext="hello";
  
   $scope.FontSize = function(start, end) {
    var size = [];
      for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
          size.push(i);
        }
      return size;
     };
                
    $scope.changeFont = function(size){
      $scope.newFont = {'font-size':size+'px'};
     };
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="editor">
            <label for="kys_font_size"> font size:</label>
            <select ng-model="kys_selected_font" id="fontsize" name="kys_font_size" ng-options="page for page in FontSize(1, 150)" ng-change="changeFont(kys_selected_font)">
               </select>   
               <input type="text"  ng-model="name1">
                 <p ng-style="newFont">{{name1}}</p>
          </div>
```

Comment: It will throw an exception without the controller definition too.

Comment: ThakYou it worked, I have edited my code and i get same error with name1 can u please tell me what i have done wrong now?

Comment: @ ste2425 if not use ng-controller in view so its work correctly. please test it.

Comment: @SSH Yup your right, but your example does use `ngController` and for someone learning angular missing that info out could really confuse them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an app module and a controller:

```
angular.module('JsApp', [])
  .controller('testing', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    // This will change when you write in the input
    $scope.YourName = 'John Doe';
  }]);
```

And it should work.